# sql server: boolean literals

Tags: sql-server, boolean

I need to substitute a "true" value into queries condition. How can I do it?

1 , true didn't work. Do I really have to write 7=7 or some crap of this kind?

Comment: +1, interesting question (I always use 1=1, but that's not very elegant).

Comment: Since SQL Server doesn't support a boolean *data type* yet (note: `bit` is a single bit integral type), why would it support boolean literals?

Comment: If it supports evaluating a condition, it should support a way to substitute there a literal. c also doesn't support a special boolean type, but all non-zero values counted as true in conditions, and zero is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, typically 1=1 or 1=0. There is no other way in T-SQL.

Comment: There are probably plenty of people on this site who can engage in a healthy debate over the design of SQL, but I'm not one of them! :) That said, something that personally bothers me much more about booleans in SQL is the hidden/hard-to-understand concept of "UNKNOWN", which is closely tied to NULL in boolean comparisons: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/2829/